# Full text search - Contains plus wildcard and single quote

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, wildcard, wordbreaker

I have a table with a name field with this

```
Test O'neill 123
```

If I use

```
SELECT  *
    FROM    table F
    WHERE   CONTAINS ( F.*, '"Test O''neill 123"' )
```

it works fine but if I use a wildcard `*` I get no results.

```
SELECT  *
    FROM    table f
    WHERE   CONTAINS ( F.*, '"Test O''neill 123*"' )
```

why is this ?
I am using a parser for my search terms and this is adding the wildcard `*`

I checked some sites, about escaping the `'` but I haven't found anything referred to this..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You are escaping `'` correctly. I can't reproduce this problem with SQL Server 2014. What version are you using?

Comment: sql server 14 too.. could be something about collation or languages ? I have no clue abuot this, I am not a dba, just a regualr developer, so I am not sure where to look at..

Comment: Not sure. In case it helps, I'm using collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS and language is English.

Comment: what I've found is that the apostrophe is a word breaker so I cannot use wildcards, only exact matches

Comment: Are you using a custom stoplist? What is the datatype & size of the name field? Is the text stored as `Test O'neill 123` exactly or is this part of a longer string?

Comment: it is stored exactly like that. There is a stoplist, and in a table related sys.fulltext_stopwords I see there is a stopword 'o', which is the first part of O'Neill.. could that be related ? I don't understand exactly how is this used. Datatype is nvarchar(200)

Comment: The stoplist could be a factor but so far it hasn't made a difference in my tests, even with 'o' as a stopword. Was this database upgraded or imported from an older version of SQL Server?

Comment: I think I've found that our language is "Neutral" and there the apostrophe is a break word while in English it is not

Comment: @Gonzalo.- you can check your server collation `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Collation')`

Comment: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The problem** is due to the combination of 1) using the Neutral language 2) plus a stoplist for your full text index 3) plus unexpected behavior when using a wildcard in a search that includes stopwords.

The Neutral language doesn't cover all of the nuances of the English language, so at index-time it considers `O'neill` to be 2 separate words `O` and `neill`. Then your stoplist considers `O` to be a stopword so this "word" is not added to the index, only `neill` is.

At search-time, the search engine typically ignores stop words in multi-word phrases. For example, searching for `Contains(*, '"we x people"')` will match the text `...we the people...`, `x` and `the` both being stopwords and thus automatically "matching" each other. (I use the term "matching" loosely because the search engine is not matching the stopwords, but rather it knows that `people` is 1 word away from `we`.)

So you might expect the wildcard search `Contains(*, '"we the people*"')` to also find its match, *except that it does not when using a stoplist*. If it weren't for the stopword `the` in the search phrase, or if `the` was not considered a stopword, the search would work fine. I really can't explain this behavior but I suspect it has something to do with the way the word positions are computed. I also suspect it is not the intended behavior.

So back to your case, `Contains(*, '"Test O''neill 123"')` will find a match but the wildcard search `Contains(*, '"Test O''neill 123*"')` does not. (You can even simplify the search to `Contains(*, '"O''neill*"')` and you'll see that it still does not find a match.) The combination of the stopword `O` with a wildcard runs into the problem I explained in the last paragraph. This is the crux of the problem stated in your question.

**Solutions** ranging from most-effective to least-effective-but-possibly-more-practical-for-your-case:

1) Change the language on your full text index to English and re-index. This will cause `O'neill` to be treated as 1 word and thus you'll avoid the weird wildcard behavior that I explained. You can change the language in the full text index properties via SQL Server Management Studio or by dropping and recreating the index as follows:

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON MyTable DROP (Column1) 
GO
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON MyTable ADD (Column1 LANGUAGE [English])
-- repeat for each column in the index
```

2) If you need to keep using the Neutral language, consider removing `O` from your stoplist and re-index.

```
ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST MyStoplist DROP 'o' LANGUAGE 'Neutral';
```

3) Or don't use a stoplist if you don't need one.

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON MyTable SET STOPLIST = OFF
```

4) If none of the above solutions are practical, consider removing stopwords from the search phrase, or at least the `O'` prefix in surnames.